# How to use This to improve and simplify code

Tags: jquery

I have several articles on a page and I have a plus sign to expand the text. The code that I have done need to be more effective. This code will only work if I have one article since all articles will be affected when I click on the plus sign.

I guess my code could be improved by using `this`, but I'm not sure how and would preciate some guidance and tips to be able to improve it.

```
<article>
<header>
    <img src="bilderGuide/bilderTips/oresundsbron.jpg" alt="Öresundsbron"/>
        <div class="articleContent">
            <div class="imageTextContainer">
            <p class="image">Some text for the image</p>
            </div>
            <h2>Headline</h2>
            <p>
            Text that are always visible....
            </p>
            <p class="extraTips1">
            Here is the hidden text
            </p>
            <!--<a id="tips1" href="#">Show the rest</a>-->
            <div class="articleContentArrow"></div>
            <div class="plus"><a href="#" id="tips1" ><img src="bilderGuide/bilderLayout/plus.png" /></a></div>
        </div>
</header>
```

```
            $("#tips1").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".extraTips1").slideToggle("fast");
            var src = $('.plus img').attr('src');
            if(src == "bilderGuide/bilderLayout/plus.png") {
                $(".plus img").attr("src","bilderGuide/bilderLayout/minus.png");
                }
                else {
                $(".plus img").attr("src","bilderGuide/bilderLayout/plus.png");
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to bind your click event to something all the articles will have. IDs are unique, so `#tip1` is out. I think your `<div class="plus">` would be a good alternative.

```
$('div.plus').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // are you sure you need this?
    var article = $(this).parents('article');
    var extras = article.find('p.extraTips1').slideToggle('fast');
    var img = article.find('.plus img');
    if(img.attr('src') == "bilderGuide/bilderLayout/plus.png") {
        img.attr('src','bilderGuide/bilderLayout/minus.png');
    }
    else {
        img.attr('src','bilderGuide/bilderLayout/plus.png');
    }
});
```

When the event is passed, `this` refers to the HTML element, not a jQuery element. What we'll do first is get the base container element and cache it. Any time we need to find an element within article, it searches a much smaller subset of elements - this more efficient and also allows you to use the same event for multiple articles.

Comment: I'm using e.preventDefault(); because there is "#" in the link tag and that would otherwise cause the browser to jump up to the top.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but the images are not changing from plus when the user click on it to expand. And when the text is expanded, it should swap to the minus icon. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var path = 'bilderGuide/bilderLayout/';

$(".expand").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prev().slideToggle("fast");
    var src = $(this).next(".plus img").attr('src');
    if (src == path + "plus.png") {
        $(this).next(".plus img").attr("src", path + "minus.png");
    } else {
        $(this).next(".plus img").attr("src", path + "plus.png");
    }
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/Ya6ET/)**

Comment: You should move the `path` variable into the function. Global variables are bad.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you have lot of articles in your page. You should use different id's for each element. So you can use [`selectors`](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to bind events to an element. Try:

```
$("a[id^=tips]").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().siblings("p.extraTips1").slideToggle("fast");
            var src = $('.plus img').attr('src');
            if(src == "bilderGuide/bilderLayout/plus.png") {
                $(".plus img").attr("src","bilderGuide/bilderLayout/minus.png");
                }
                else {
                $(".plus img").attr("src","bilderGuide/bilderLayout/plus.png");
                }
        });
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dhy7U/)</kbd>